# replacement for Gwt cell table

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT cell table in the grid to maintain data rows and i need some events between the columns in the same row and others rows too

for example:

If i selected some value from combo box  in first column and i need to disable an text box in the last column.

I tried in many ways and failed to linkup those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CellTable is very awkward for these kinds of interactions.  You must redraw the entire table anytime you want any cell to change.

So: when the first cell changes, update the state of the second cell, and redraw the table.

If possible, use something besides CellTable for this interface like a Grid or FlexTable.

Comment: but i need something like to edit the cells in the grid ..how it will possible in the grid .

Comment: @Riley: you can redraw a single row, given its index, with `redrawRow`.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer wow, how did I miss that! *runs off to implement*